# Solr: copy a text field to another and transform into keywords

Tags: java, solr, lucene, keyword, analyzer

I'm pretty new to Solr, and what I'm trying to achieve is to build a keywords list and store it with other fields in a document. So I have a text field in my solr schema defined as :

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

What I need to do is to make another field to store keywords, exactly the same as they would be after processing the title after analyzing (tokenizing, stemming etc.). The goal is to expose the keywords associated with a document (built from title) so that one can obtain them with that document.

While it is possible to process the title using Lucene analyzer (the code is in Java) and submit pre-built `keywords` field with each document, I wonder is there a way to achieve that using [copyField](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) and transforming a text field into keywords. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stored` always contains the non-analyzed input. It sounds like you're looking for the `termVectors` feature: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent

Comment: Thanks, yes, that was exactly what I was looking for. I was able to figure that out before this answer, but this is the correct answer anyway.